# Incorrect image recycling in RecyclerView

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview, porter-duff

I have a `RecyclerView` with an icon in each row. The icon should be colored dynamically, so I use a white icon and apply a color filter when binding the view. Oddly enough, I end up with a lot of discrepancies in the resulting view.

In this example I'm attempting to make every third row red and the rest green (note #18):

[image]

Below is the adapter. As you can see, I'm applying the altered icon to the `ImageView` every time I rebind the holder, presumably leaving no room for the old recycled image.

```
public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final Context context;

    public TestAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public TestAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TestAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 200;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final ImageView image;
        private final TextView text;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }

        public void bindItem(int position) {
            // pick color depending on the position
            final int color = ContextCompat.getColor(context,
                    position%3 == 0 ? android.R.color.holo_red_light : android.R.color.holo_green_light
            );

            // set text content and color
            text.setText("#" + position);
            text.setTextColor(color);

            // create icon from the resource and set filter
            final Drawable icon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_brightness, null);
            icon.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

            image.setImageDrawable(icon);
        }
    }

}
```

`item_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        tools:text="text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What gives?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want have different types of views, instead of picking position, think about overriding `getItemViewType` method.

Comment: The problem is that in the real project the color may be arbitrary, it comes from a server.

Comment: That's interesting. Have you tested this with different icons, rather than with the filter, to see whether you still get the same results?

Comment: @PPartisan Yeah, it works just fine with different icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having read your comments, I'm not sure whether this is suitable to your requirements. However, I was able to replicate the expected behaviour by setting the "brightness" drawable with the `android:src` element in the layout file, then applying the filter to the `ImageView` (rather than the icon):

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public RecyclerViewAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.bindItem(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 200;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final ImageView image;
        private final TextView text;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }

        public void bindItem(int position) {

            final int color = ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.getContext(),
                    position % 3 == 0 ? android.R.color.holo_red_light : android.R.color.holo_green_light
            );

            text.setText("#" + position);
            text.setTextColor(color);

            image.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

It also works if you set the icon dynamically, but apply the filter to the `ImageView`:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final ImageView image;
    private final TextView text;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    }

    public void bindItem(int position) {

        final int color = ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.getContext(),
                position % 3 == 0 ? android.R.color.holo_red_light : android.R.color.holo_green_light
        );

        text.setText("#" + position);
        text.setTextColor(color);

        Drawable icon = getIcon();

        image.setImageDrawable(icon);
        image.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private Drawable getIcon() {
        return (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                ? image.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_brightness_1_white_24dp, null)
                : image.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_brightness_1_white_24dp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly!
Meanwhile, I started reading the source code for `BitmapDrawable` and stumbled upon a really useful comment:
"A mutable BitmapDrawable still shares its Bitmap with any other Drawable that comes from the same resource".
So another thing that works is calling `icon = icon.mutate()` prior to setting `setColorFilter()` but I like your solution much more.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code segment in your bindview

```
int color;
if(position%3 == 0){
    color = android.R.color.holo_red_light;
    text.setText("#" + position);
    text.setTextColor(color);
    Drawable icon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_brightness, null);
    icon.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    image.setImageDrawable(icon);

} else{
    color = android.R.color.holo_red_light;
    text.setText("#" + position);
    text.setTextColor(color);
    Drawable icon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_brightness, null);
    icon.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    image.setImageDrawable(icon);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it's pretty much the same logic. Unfortunately, the issue remains.